# How to colourize variables inside strings at Geany?

Tags: bash, plugins, geany

I am trying to migrate from gedit, using oblivion theme.

At GEdit (on linux), the variables inside strings are colorized differently than other words on the same string (it is not perfect but is something).

Is there some option or plugin that could provide that same feature at Geany, at least for shell-scripts?